# Strange behaviour for unique_pointer in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I tried writing this class

```
#include <memory>

class ContainerUnique
{
public:

    ContainerUnique(void);
    ~ContainerUnique(void);

private:
    std::unique_ptr<UniqueElement> u;
};
```

Where UniqueElement is a POD class defined elsewhere. I now define the constructor body like this:

```
ContainerUnique::ContainerUnique(void)
{
    auto tmp = new UniqueElement(1);

    this->u(tmp); // u is a unique_ptr<UniqueElement>. Should this call compile?
}
```

And it complies without exceptions. Running the program I find that after the constructor of `ContainerUnique` has been called, `u` contains a null pointer.

Is this the intended behaviour? And what unique_ptr method am I actually calling?

Comment: Not sure about the problems you are encountering.  But avoid them by initializing the member variable u in the constructor's initialaztrion list.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution I used in my real code, but I'm still not sure about what is happening in the example.

Comment: Try printing the type of your auto variable.  Not sure if typeid works.  Once you know the type the rest should be easy.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This is a known problem with VS2010's `unique_ptr`.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/633905/visual-c-ill-formed-unique-ptr-function-call-syntax) It *publicly* inherits from its deleter if it's empty as an optimization (empty base optimization). The downside to the public inheritance is that all members of the deleter also become available members of `unique_ptr`, in this case its `operator()(T*)` that deletes the pointer.

The bug is fixed in VS2012's library where the inheritance is changed to private.

Comment: ah, you beat me to it. Good find.

Answer (score 9):

You are calling `default_delete< UniqueElement >::operator () ( UniqueElement* ptr )`, because uniqe_ptr derives from it (to benefit from empty base class optimization), and it deletes `ptr`. It's not exactly intended behavior for you, although I don't think the standard forbids it.

Answer (score 2):

It should be done like

```
ContainerUnique::ContainerUnique(void):u(new UniqueElement(1)) {
}
```

Comment: This is the way I solved the problem in my production code, but I'm still unsure about what's happening in the example.